# What's the best way to store several businesses opening and closing times in a database

Tags: database, postgresql

All the other questions related to this had been asked years ago, and so i was wondering what the best way to store openign and closing times for businesses in a POSTGRES database is. Is it best to store it in its own table? Maybe have the days of the week as columns? I saw that answer for ten years ago. Do these type of things change over time, or does the best way to do something stay constant in terms of storing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL for Opening Hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721533/sql-for-opening-hours)

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1036603/642706

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19545597/642706

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4797067/642706

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4464898/642706

Comment: That was asked 10 years ago. I wanted to know if there is a better implementation now

Comment: You should explain what you think might have changed.

Comment: I don't know. I'm pretty new to this area

Comment: I think it is fair to have a duplicate question every ten years however, in the event that something has changed

Comment: Even if the answer has changed, the question may still be a duplicate. If so, new answers to the old question should be written, not to new questions. We prefer to have it all in one place (not that I know of anything that has changed, nor can rule out that something has).